# How can I call for something in a data.frame when the destinction has to be done in two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry for the very specific question, but I have a file as such:

```
             Adj      Year     man   mt      wm       wmt    by     bytl   gr      grtl
3            careless 1802     0     126     0        54     0      13     0       51
4            careless 1803     0     166     0        72     0       1     0       18
5            careless 1804     0     167     0        58     0       2     0       25
6            careless 1805     0     117     0         5     0       5     0        7
7            careless 1806     0     408     0        88     0      15     0       27
8            careless 1807     0     214     0        71     0       9     0       32
...
560              mean 1939    21    5988     8      1961     0    1152     0     1512
561              mean 1940    20    5810     6      1965     1     914     0     1444
562              mean 1941    10    6062     4      2097     5     964     0     1550
563              mean 1942     8    5352     2      1660     2     947     2     1506
564              mean 1943    14    5145     5      1614     1     878     4     1196
565              mean 1944    42    5630     6      1939     1     902     0     1583
566              mean 1945    17    6140     7      2192     4    1004     0     1906
```

Now I have to call for specific values (e.g. [careless,1804,man] or [mean, 1944, wmt].
Now I have no clue how to do that, one possibility would be to split the data.frame and create an array if I'm correct. But I'd love to have a simpler solution.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: May be you need `library(dplyr); df1 %>% filter(Adj=="careless" & Year == 1804 & man!=0)`  The `man` values are not specified in the post, so not sure

Comment: Looks like you need to `?Extract` parts of the data using `?logic`.

Comment: Could you please give a clearer example of what you want?  You say  [careless,1804,man].   Do you mean you want all of the values of the man column where Adj==careless and Year==1804?

Comment: Well I know there will only be one row with Adj==careless and Year==1804 and I then need to extract the value in the column man. Sorry if it is unclear!

Comment: Try, `df[df$Adj == "careless" & df$Year == 1804, "man"]`

Comment: You are a god @RonakShah !
Thank you to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsetting for specific values in `Adj` and `Year` column and selecting the `man` column will give you the required output.

```
df[df$Adj == "careless" & df$Year == 1804, "man"]
```